# Simpler way to type assert a two-dimensional interface array from json unmarshal

Tags: json, go, type-assertion

I need to unmarshal a complex json data with a [][]interface{} array in it. I want to use more abstract struct type to unmarshal it, but Golang can only recognize it as []interface{}.

example code:

```
// I want to use this, but not work
var r1 = struct {
    Data map[string]interface{}
}{}

// Works well, but too complex if data nest much
var r2 = struct {
    Data struct{
        P1 int64
        P2 [][]interface{}
    }
}{}

jsonData := []byte(`{"data" :{"p1": 0, "p2":[["1", null], ["2", null] ]}}`)

json.Unmarshal (jsonData, &r1)
_, ok := r1.Data["p2"].([][]interface{})
fmt.Println(ok)

fmt.Println("======")

_, ok = r1.Data["p2"].([]interface{})
fmt.Println(ok)

fmt.Println("======")

json.Unmarshal (jsonData, &r2)
fmt.Println(r2.Data.P2)
```

output:

```
false
======
true
======
[[1 <nil>] [2 <nil>]]
```

Comment: Based purely on the short sample data in your code, your data seems to have no consistent structure. If that's the case, there's nothing you can really do beyond unmarshaling into `interface{}` and using type switches/assertions to work with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:

You need to apply twice an assertion on your empty interface{} type.

[image]

https://play.golang.org/p/AeV6_fC3vYI